# Rails - join table deletion

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

My Lab model:

```
class Lab < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :chain_offers, dependent: :delete_all
    has_many :offers, through: :chain_offers
```

My Join model (chain_offers)

```
class ChainOffer < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :lab
    belongs_to :offer
```

My Offer model

```
class Offer < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :chain_offers
    has_many :labs, through: :chain_offers
```

If I try to delete Lab, it gets delete, records in ChainOffer table are also deleted, but after checking `Offer.all.count` the count is still the same as before deletion.

Doing:

```
place = Place.find(place_id)
place.offers.each do |offer|
    offer.destroy
end
place.destroy
```

solves that problem, but I was wondering if there is a way to set up associations so I do not have to write additional code.

Comment: Be clear about the difference between #delete and #destroy. You probably want to #destroy.

Also, if you destroy a Lab, then it sounds like you want the ChainOffers to also be destroyed, and then any Offers -- doesn't that then require that other ChainOffers (that link to different Labs) also be destroyed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding of how a many to many relationship works is simply incorrect.

Lets take this example:

```
class Patient < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :appointments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :doctors, through: :appointments
end

class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :patient
  belongs_to :doctor
end

class Doctor < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :doctors, through: :appointments
end
```

If we where to delete a patient with `Patient.find(1).destroy` it should also delete any rows on `appointments` with `appointments.patient_id = 1`.

It should NOT destroy any rows on the `doctors` table! That would remove the doctor from other patients and is not what you want.

Comment: That is correct. I was thinking about my relationship as not many-to-many, as I am not using it this way, but I forgot why I set it up like this in the first place. Thank you for clear explanation!